# Wordpress get_adjacent_post() — skip first post

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm using the Wordpress `get_adjacent_post()` function to retrieve and return next and previous post data.

However I would like to always skip the first post, and have it loop back to the beginning. For example:

```
Post 0
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
Post 5
```

When viewing Post 1, it should show 'Post 5' as the previous post, rather than Post 0.

Comment: `get_adjacent_post()` doesn't skip posts, you'll have to write your own function for that, probably getting all posts and iterating

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing now. Also just wondering, is it possible to get_adjacent_post() from any post with the post ID? From what I can see, it's not possible, right?